# Resizing an image inside a <li>

Tags: html, css

Looking to resize a big image down to a thumbnail within a list item:

HTML code

```
<div class="header">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="index.html"><img src="imgs/logo.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>             
    <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.header {
  width: 100%;
}
.nav {
  max-width: 92.5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1% 0% 0.75% 1%;
}
.nav li {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
```

No matter what I try, the image breaks out of the `li` "box" ... I can obviously resize it to fit inside, but I want it to take up the entire `li` box based on how big the other `li` are... any suggestions?

Comment: did you try width:100%

Comment: yeah, didn't work!

Comment: do you have link to website or fiddle? OR give a width to your image

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqo79yxm/2/ .. I want to get that huge image down to fit within the LI box (outlined in black)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add image as background:

```
background-image: url('https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg');
```

check this

https://jsfiddle.net/nqo79yxm/4/

Answer (score 0):

Provide the height to the img tag.

Like below:

```
img{
    height :20px;
}
```

Now the image will have a fixed height, otherwise the image will take `height: auto`.